Is Yocto SDK binary compatible within release?
Ignoring custom layers, let's say I have a Poky SDK built for image built from kirkstone branch.
Would the same SDK work with an image build from kirkstone branch 200 (or 500 or 5000) commits later?
I suppose this is the point of releases, but couldn't find definitive answer to this question.
So can I use the same SDK even as the image evolves or should I have separate version of the SDK for each version of the image?
